# Bug while trying to open DatePicker when Picker is opened

Tags: ios, swiftui

I wanted to open DatePicker when Picker is already opened, but result of it is that DatePicker is acting as opened (it label is blue colored), but nothing is presented and also while trying to again click on DatePicker it is not doing anything.

I created some MRE -

```
enum SomeCases: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case first = "First"
    case second = "Second"
    case third = "Third"
    case fourth = "Fourth"
    
    public var id: String { rawValue }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var someCases: SomeCases = .first
    @State private var someDate: Date = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 150){
            Picker("First picker", selection: $someCases) {
                ForEach(SomeCases.allCases) { someCase in
                    Text(someCase.rawValue)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
            
            DatePicker("Date picker", selection: $someDate)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Also got this message -

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <_UIDatePickerContainerViewController: 0x7f78f8b049b0> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7f78f301b800> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVVS_P10$11d30daf821BridgedNavigationView8RootView_: 0x7f78f301aa00>) which is already presenting <_UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController: 0x7f78f399d810>.
```

Tried to look for some answers online, but there is always solution with using .sheet, which I don't want to use here. Also it is iOS 15.

Comment: I did a quick test and I don't think this happens if you put everything in a Form or List. I.e. replace `VStack (spacing: 150)` with `Form`. Hope that works for your user interface requirements.

Comment: @Daniel - hmmm, I actually tried to use both components and error is still here..

Comment: @MarkoMarkovic - this looks like a ... well, "bug" or "unfortunate side effect." Tapping outside the *presented* first picker should dismiss it... but, it appears that tapping on the `DatePicker` triggers ***its present*** method before calling dismiss to remove the first picker. One workaround (may or may not be suitable for you): put the first picker `.inline` in an overlay or ZStack layout and use a button to show/hide it.